# Jira bugs summary per a user story

Tags: jira, summary, user-stories

I'm looking for an idea how to improve visibility of user stories progress in Jira+GreenHopper.

**How we work now**: we put all our User Stories into Jira, break them down into sub-tasks for development, then our testers link bugs in Jira to appropriate user stories. On our project dashboard we have a filter like "show name, status, completion %  where fixVersion = current_sprint order by priority desc".

**Our problem**: in order to understand if a user story marked as 100% done can really be demonstrated to our customer, we need to make sure if it has no critical bugs and has no more than N low-priority bugs. But now we need to manually go over each user story one by one to calculate such figures.

**Question**: Any ideas if it's possible to show bugs count of each priority in the list of user stories in current sprint? For simplicity, we would consider like:

- High: not resolved bugs of Blocker + Critical priority;
- Medium: not resolved bugs of Major + Medium priority;
- Low: not resolved bugs of Minor + Trivial priority;

So, such list would look like

```
US name | US completion % | High-pri bugs # | Med-pri bugs # | Low-pri bugs #
```

Ideas of the easiest way? anything built on standard Jira gadgets/queries? or any custom plugin you might know to use for that? or even if anything should be developed?  Thanks!

Comment: The JTricks jql plugin might have some JQL function to filter by linked issues, but then the different filters would need to be combined. You could also use the CLI to extract the data and combine it for the report.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new issue type, may be call it "Sub-Bug". This issue type should be available only when user tries to create subtask under a story.

When QA validates a story and finds the issues, ask them to create sub-task under the story and select "Sub-bug" as issue type.

Now you can easily follow that all subtasks (which includes actual subtask and su-bug) are completed before you move story to "Done" status.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (read only) custom field which stores the number of all linked issues. This custom field can be shown in your search results.
Maybe this is something for you: [JIRA Misc Custom Fields](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.innovalog.jmcf.jira-misc-custom-fields)

*This custom field can be used easily in filters. The issue count can than be displayed in e.g. confluence pages. That confluence page you can show to your customers.*